# How to combine a pyside frame with a button layout

Tags: python, layout, button, pyqt, pyside

I came across a pyside script demonstrating a frame, and pyside script demonstrating buttons and box layout.

I made a primitive attempt to combine the two scripts, but I can't get both of the following functions to work at the same time:  run_button_app(True) and run_frame_app(True)

One of the functions uses this statement: app_frame = QApplication([])
and the other uses this statement:  app1 = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
The tutorials I used did not include material explaining these things.  I've ordered a book on Pyside and PyQt programming, but it hasn't arrived yet.

I'm trying to figure out how to use the frame (e.g., to put a couple of frames in window, and put my buttons in one of the frames), but I haven't been able to figure that out yet, nor where to get info (example? tutorial?) about how to use the frame.

I am a pyside and python newbie. 
Any tips (e.g., links to relevant tutorials) would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
              Marc

```
    """
    Cannibalized by Marc from 
        http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/
        ZetCode PySide tutorial  author: Jan Bodnar    website: zetcode.com 
            and    
        # explore QFrame()   #http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/366177
    """

    import sys
    from PySide.QtCore import *
    from PySide.QtGui import *
    from PySide import QtGui

    initiate_app = False

    class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):
            super(Example, self).__init__()
            # The following 4 lines are from "Window_with_frame.py"
            # setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
            # self.setGeometry(100, 150, width, height)
            # self.setWindowTitle(title)
            # self.make_frame()

            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

            okButton = QtGui.QPushButton("OKh1_1")
            cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel1_2")
            ThirdButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Third1_3")
            hbox2_1Button = QtGui.QPushButton("hbox2_Btn1")
            hbox2_2Button = QtGui.QPushButton("hbox2_Btn2")
            hbox3_1Button = QtGui.QPushButton("hbox3_Btn1")
            hbox3_2Button = QtGui.QPushButton("hbox3_Btn2")
            Vbox1Button = QtGui.QPushButton("Vbox1Button")
            Vbox2Button = QtGui.QPushButton("Vbox2Button")
            NewQqPtA1Button = QtGui.QPushButton("NewQqPtA1")
            NewQqPtB2Button = QtGui.QPushButton("NewQqPtB2")

            hbox1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            hbox1.addStretch(1)
            hbox1.addWidget(okButton)
            hbox1.addWidget(cancelButton)
            hbox1.addWidget(ThirdButton)

            hbox2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            hbox2.addStretch(1)
            hbox2.addWidget(hbox2_1Button)
            hbox2.addWidget(hbox2_2Button)
            hbox1.addLayout(hbox2)

            hbox3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            hbox3.addStretch(1)        
            hbox3.addWidget(hbox3_1Button)
            hbox3.addWidget(hbox3_2Button)

            vbox1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
            vbox1.addStretch(1)
            vbox1.addWidget(Vbox1Button)
            vbox1.addLayout(hbox1)
            #vbox1.addLayout(hbox2)
            vbox1.addLayout(hbox3)

            vbox2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
            vbox2.addStretch(1)
            vbox2.addWidget(Vbox2Button)
            vbox2.addLayout(vbox1)

            self.setLayout(vbox2)    

            self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
            self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')
            #self.make_frame()
            self.show()

    # The class is from "Window_with_frame.py"

    class FrameTester(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, title, width, height, parent=None):
            # create the window (this will be instance self)
            QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            # setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
            self.setGeometry(100, 150, width, height)
            self.setWindowTitle(title)
            self.make_frame()

        def make_frame(self):
            frame = QFrame(self)
            frame.setLineWidth(3)
            frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box|QFrame.Sunken)        
            # this will not have the effect you hope for
            #frame.setFrameRect(QRect(10, 10, 20, 20))       
            layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
            layout.addWidget(frame)        
            self.setLayout(layout)



    def run_frame_app(initiate_app = False):        
        # create the Qt Application
        if initiate_app == True:        
            app_frame = QApplication([])        
            title = "Window"
            width = 800
            height = 600
            tester = FrameTester(title, width, height)
            tester.show()        
            # run the main Qt event loop
            app_frame.exec_()


    def run_button_app(initiate_app = False):   
        # create the Qt Application
        if initiate_app == True:        
            app1 = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
            ex = Example()
            run_frame_app()
            sys.exit(app1.exec_())    



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        #run_button_app(True)
        run_frame_app(True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run two `QAplication` instances at once, 
here some information in this [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/firstprograms/).

I dont fully understand what are you trying to do, but if you want to add `Example` widget (with buttons) to `FrameTester`, you need to create some layout in `FrameTester` and add `Example` instance to this layout (there are many tutorials on it).

If you want `Example` widget to have frame, you need to subclass `QFrame`:

```
class Example(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLineWidth(3)
        self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box|QFrame.Sunken)  
# ...
```

Tip for the future, when you defining some `Widget`, provide `parent` argument to `__init__` function, so it can be used in other places.

To learn more try [zetcode tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/), [PySide documentation](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/index.html)